# как называется данное выражение и как оно работает?

Tags: java, mysql

INSERT INTO user2(name, last name, age) Values(?, ?, ?);

о чем говорят вопросительные знаки?? О пустых аргументах?

Comment: не понимаю как он работает( 
как потом положить данные вместо этих вопросительных знаков?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно легче ответить на вопрос, если предоставляется больше исходного кода, который вызывает вопрос, Вы же указали только запрос из исходного кода.

Скорее всего это выражение для [PreparedStatement](https://metanit.com/java/database/2.6.php), рекомендую прочитать.
То есть вопросительный знак это как бы виртуальная переменная, которую вы укажите при подготовке `PreparedStatement`. Обычно такие переменные называются "wildcard" - подстановочная переменная.

Например в Вашем случае подготовка `PreparedStatement` будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO user2(Name, LastName, Age) Values(?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
String name = "Иван";
String lastName = "Иванов";
int age = 35;
preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
preparedStatement.setString(2, lastName);
preparedStatement.setInt(3, age);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ! этого вполне достаточно для понимания !